# Oracle SQL query Step Number

Tags: sql, oracle

I hope you guys can help me with my problem.
Right now, I have a query below:

```
SELECT ID, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID)), Date 
FROM MYTABLE;
```

the output is:

```
No. Identification No.  Date
1   100010              11-Jul-15
2   100011              7-Jul-15
```

I would like the output to be, is this possible?:

```
No. Identification No.  Date
1   100010              7-Jul-15
2   100010              10-Jul-15
3   100010              11-Jul-15
1   100011              7-Jul-15
2   100011              10-Jul-15
3   100011              11-Jul-15
```

Comment: There must be a missing record in the sample data provided.

Comment: The logic behind your output is not clear. Why not 8 and 9 july? and what if you have another row with, for example, 3 july?

Comment: Somehow I don't get how your SQL-Statement is connected to the output - the output of ROW_NUMBER() surely can't be your "Identification No" ...
Maybe you want to partition the output of ROW_NUMBER() like so:
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY <???> ORDER BY ID)

Answer (score 0):

You need a list of the dates:

```
select d.dte, t.id,
       row_number() over (partition by id order by dte) as num
from t cross join
     (select date '2015-07-07' as dte from dual union all
      select date '2015-07-10' as dte from dual union all
      select date '2015-07-11' as dte from dual
     ) d;
```

Comment: I added the partition by and it worked. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to partition the row_number()

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date) as Row_ord, 
       ID, 
       Date 
FROM MYTABLE;
```